# How to show completion percentage in a bootstrap card in python dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am building a dash application and have calculated a completion_percentage for the project completion. I am using dash_bootstrap_components and want to show that percentage inside the card. Is there any way to do so or is there any other way to graphically show the completion percentage on the application page?
Below is the code which I am using as part of the layout

```
completion_percentage = str((closed_tickets / total_tickets) * 100)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Project Analytics",),
        html.P(
            children="Get the status!",
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure=fig,
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            figure=pie_chart
        ),
        dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody(
                [
                    html.H4("Completion Percentage", className="card-title"),
                    dbc.CardText(completion_percentage)
                ]
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

The above is giving me error as cardtext excpets P or Div. Can someone help with the following.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> AttributeError: CardText has been removed from dash-bootstrap-components. Set className='card-text' on a html component such as Div, or P instead. CardText originally used P.

So you can use `html.P` or `html.Div` where you're now using `dbc.CardText`.

Example:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

closed_tickets = 10
total_tickets = 80
completion_percentage = str((closed_tickets / total_tickets) * 100)

app = Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Project Analytics",),
        html.P(
            children="Get the status!",
        ),
        dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody(
                [
                    html.H4("Completion Percentage", className="card-title"),
                    html.P(completion_percentage)
                ]
            )
        )
    ]
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/card/

Comment: Where are you binding the completion_percentage  here though?

Comment: @Jayashri I'm not. I've used a generic example to illustrate the idea and because the example in your question is incomplete. But like I mentioned at the start of my answer , the problem is that you're using `dbc.CardText`. So simply replace all instances of `dbc.CardText` with `html.P`. In your example `completion_percentage` is also not used btw.

Comment: I edited the question. I am using html.Div itself. I have just posted the snippet where I was trying to pass completion_percentage in the card. I am not sure how to pass it in the card so as to view it in the dashboard

Comment: @Jayashri See my updated answer. I omitted the graphs, because these are irrelevant to the question problem and I don't know how you're creating them.